# Stacked tabs in dropdown menu in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

What i am creating is similar to this. I found this while researching on stackexchange.

However, i want the dropdown to open on mouseover. I am able to create a bootstrap navbar with mouseover dropdowns, but unable to add mouseover action to the example given above. Any ideas?

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>


  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>           </li>
      <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a data-target="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">HOME asdfasdfsda</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">PROFILE asdfafas</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">MESSAGES asdfdas</div>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pv2Lc/7/

Comment: What did you try to achieve that result? SO is mostly intended for questions about *your* code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/70ytg4yf/

HTML unchanged

No JS

CSS:

```
.dropdown:hover {
    /* so that no mouseout is triggered when moving to the menu */
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    /* move up since default is lower because of padding */
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```